# How should I use streams in this situation

Tags: java, list, java-stream

I am new using `stream` in `java` and would like to know if there exists a way to optimize this code. I am confused when I should use `map` or filter in this situation

```
public Active get(List<Person> personList){
        Active a = null;
        for(Person person:personList){
            if(person.getActives() != null && !person.getActives().isEmpty()){
                for(Active active: person.getActives()){
                    if(active.getStatus().equals(SOME_VALUE)){
                        if (a == null || a.getDueDate().isAfter(active.getDueDate())) {
                            a = active;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return a;
}
```

Comment: Well, what is your *actual problem* in turning this into stream operations?

Answer (score 2):

```
  Active a = personList.stream()
         .filter(person -> person.getActives() != null && !person.getActives().isEmpty()
         .flatMap(person -> person.getActivities())
         .filter(activity -> active.getStatus().equals(SOME_VALUE))
         .reduce(null, (pos_a, activity) -> 
           (pos_a == null || a.getDueDate().isAfter(active.getDueDate()))? activity: pos_a)
    return a;
```

This will get all the Persons that have Activities, stream all the Activity's (flatMap) and filter those on their status and then reduce the list keeping the oldest one

Comment: `reduce(null, …)` will throw an exception when there are no elements. Better use `min(Comparator.comparing(Active::getDueDate)).orElse(null)`